# How to make Angular Material 6 components smaller?

Tags: angular

[Angular Material 6](https://material.angular.io/) components are so big.

I prefer a smaller size of all controls, Can anyone guide me for the best way?

Can I change the typography without destroying grid system, ratio, balancing,... in all devices?

Comment: Additionally to Wandrille answer, have you try the density option in theming or for component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reduce the size of the Angular Material Module that you use.

But if you are talking about the FONT SIZE, so yes you can do it.
Check [the doc of theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) of angular Material